404 on Hard Navigation with Parallel Routes in Next.js 14 for Nested Route
I'm implementing tab groups using Parallel Routes in Next.js 14 and facing an issue where a 404 page appears only during hard navigation to /gnb/mypage/tab1. The tabs and their navigation work perfectly on initial render and when clicking between tabs. However, directly accessing /gnb/mypage/tab1 through hard navigation (e.g., entering the URL in the browser or refreshing the page) results in a 404 error. Below is my directory structure and relevant code snippets:
Directory Structure:
./src/app/gnb
├── layout.tsx
├── mypage
│   ├── @myactive
│   │   └── page.tsx
│   ├── @mysubscribe
│   │   └── page.tsx
│   ├── @tabs
│   │   ├── default.tsx
│   │   ├── layout.tsx
│   │   ├── page.tsx
│   │   ├── tab1
│   │   │   ├── default.tsx
│   │   │   └── page.tsx
│   │   └── tab2
│   │       ├── default.tsx
│   │       └── page.tsx
│   ├── layout.tsx
│   └── page.tsx
└── page.tsx

Relevant Code Snippets:
src/app/gnb/mypage/layout.tsx:
function Layout({
  children,
  tabs,
  myactive,
  mysubscribe,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  tabs: React.ReactNode;
  myactive: React.ReactNode;
  mysubscribe: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{children}</div>
      <br />
      <div>{tabs}</div>
      <br />
      <div>{myactive}</div>
      <div>{mysubscribe}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

src/app/gnb/mypage/@tabs/layout.tsx:
import Link from 'next/link';

function Layout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <Link href="/gnb/mypage/tab1">TabOne </Link>
        <Link href="/gnb/mypage/tab2">TabTwo</Link>
      </nav>
      <div>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Layout;

I've included default.tsx files in both tab1 and tab2 directories under @tabs to handle default rendering. Despite this setup, directly accessing the /gnb/mypage/tab1 URL results in a 404 page.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with Parallel Routes in Next.js 14, or can anyone spot what might be causing this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

How
Add default.tsx to src/app/gnb/@myactive and src/app/gnb@mysubscribe will hidden 404 page.
Why
/gnb/mypage/tab1/page.tsx use src/app/gnb/mypage/layout.tsx,so it will load myactive slot and mysubscribe slot. When nextjs hard hard navigation page cannot match Parallel Routes and it will lose it.
